# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, jasper-reports, jasper

estoy tratando de hacer un reporte en mi aplicacion Java, en Neatbeans 8.2. Dicho reporte me tomará los datos de un JTable y los imprimirá. Pero a la hora de realizar el reporte me da el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory.<clinit>(ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory.java:109)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:190)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:148)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:60)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:298)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:274)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:194)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:157)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:129)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:86)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:114)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:82)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:251)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:272)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:156)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:145)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:758)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1074)
at clases.Porcentaje.Reporte(Porcentaje.java:374)
at clases.Porcentaje.btn_ReporteActionPerformed(Porcentaje.java:743)
at clases.Porcentaje.access$000(Porcentaje.java:31)
at clases.Porcentaje$1.actionPerformed(Porcentaje.java:425)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Rule
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
```

Cabe destacar que ya tengo en las librerías de mi proyecto el .jar de common digester. He ido incluyendo librerias a medida que me las ha pedido, pero a pesar de incluir la libreria de common digester me sigue dando el error de Rule.No se si estare haciendo algo mal o necesito crear algun archivo XML. Uso el NetBeans 8.2. Este es el código de mi método de generar reportes:

```
public void Reporte(){
    List lista = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount();i++){
        Producto_Listado pl = new Producto_Listado(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1).toString(),jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(),
                jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString(),jTable1.getValueAt(i, 4).toString(),
                jTable1.getValueAt(i, 5).toString(),jTable1.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
        lista.add(pl);
    }
    JasperReport reporte;
    try{
        reporte = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("D:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Proyecto_Ter\\src\\reporte\\ReportePorcentaje.jasper");
        JasperPrint imprimir = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
        JasperViewer.viewReport(imprimir, false); //para que al cerrarse el reporte no se cierre el programa
    }catch(Exception e){
        
    }
}
```

[image: mis librerias]

ACTUALIZACION!!!!
Logré arreglar el problema agregando las siguientes librerias, pero al hacer click en el boton imprimir no sale ningun reporte, basicamente es como si no llamara a ningun metodo.

[image: jars que inserte]

Comment: tenia el primer problema , solo remplaze la libreria digestor por uan version anterior , la 2.1

Comment: Tuve un problema similar, me refiero a que no encuentra tu reporte. Te sugiero que uses una dirección estática, es decir, que le asignes una ubicación al reporte, no la default que trae.